# Change GRUB2 menu entry

Tags: linux, rhel, grub2, grub, uefi

I'm attempting to change the name of an existing entry in the GRUB2 menu from "Red Hat Enterprise Linux blah blah blah" to "My Linux Distro" (or anything!) but no matter what I do, nothing seems to affect it.

I have edited the value of GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR in /etc/default/grub to

```
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="My Linux Distro"
```

Followed by running

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg
```

As I am running UEFI boot mode.

But this does nothing on reboot. However, I can successfully change the GRUB_TIMEOUT to something like 25 and this will take effect after updating the grub.cfg file. Weird.

After some digging into how grub works, I went and read through the generated file at /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg and it seems to lack any menu entries at all.

The grub menu must be pulling the menu entry values from somewhere, but it doesn't seem to be from the grub.cfg file as it is supposed to, because there aren't any in there.

I troubleshot this by generating a test grub.cfg file as follows to see if it was actually spitting anything out, as I perhaps thought my grub2-mkconfig was broken and not creating a file, but it does create a file, albeit containing no menu entries.

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /tmp/grub_test.cfg
```

I'm at a loss as to what to do, I've tried everything I can find online and nothing is changing the entry name in the grub menu.

Comment: Do you have an `/etc/grub.d/` directory?

Answer (score 0):

RHEL now uses a version of GRUB that includes the `blscfg` module. It implements compatibility with [The Boot Loader Specification](https://uapi-group.org/specifications/specs/boot_loader_specification/).

In a nutshell: the boot menu entries for the kernels are defined by files in `/boot/loader/entries/`, one file per kernel. The entry titles are defined by the line in the file that begins with the `title` keyword.

Comment: Thank you, I had literally figured this out just before seeing this. Seems all the answers online are old so none/very few of them highlight this. Rlly appreciate it though